# Table design using CSS 2.1 and HTML 4.01 Transitional

Tags: html, screenshot, tablelayout, css

Help!

I'm struggling to make a crazy table using HTML 4.01 Transitional and CSS 2.1

Here is a picture of what the table should look like.

How would you do the left and right image?

fiddle welcome :)

thanks

[image]

Comment: What have you already tried? Can you at least show a near-finished demo, and describe where you're stuck?

Comment: i m not able to see your image dear where is the image?

Comment: What would you do is the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Bluest_cube/RLHMM/3/

Comment: beautiful. just missing closing div on the wrapper. thank you so much.